# IntelliJ cannot find Step Definitions from Feature File

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I've setup the following cucumber skeleton project using the repo from Cucumber:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

I'm using IntelliJ 2019.1.3 with the latest bundled Cucumber for Java and Gherkin plugins

I'm using Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_232"

I'm have a local Gradle install of 6.0.1 and for the project, gradlew 6.7.1

I have the following cucumber dependencies specified:

```
  testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.9.1'
  testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.9.1'
```

When I run using the command line:

`./gradlew test --rerun-tasks --info`

...the tests can be run from the RunCucumberTest JUnit runner, but I cannot configure the bundled Cucumber and Gherkin plugins to 'see' the Steps from the Feature File as they *all* remain grayed out:

[image]

Given I'm using Cucumber's own vanilla project, what can I try to resolve the issue of the Feature File failing to recognised or run the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error you are getting says:

> io.cucumber.skeleton.RunCucumberTest > Belly.a few cukes FAILED
> io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "I wait 1 hour" is >undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:

So add the following snippet into `StepDefinitions.java` file:

```
@When("I wait {int} hour")
public void i_wait_hour(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

Comment: apologies, my question was unclear - I have now clarified